# Nginx, proxy_pass on route with params and id's

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

I am trying to set a set a difficult proxy pass within Nginx. The URL itself requires a bunch id's and then has a query string at the end.

```
location /api/v1/schools/(.*)/courses/(.*)/years/(.*)/api_end_point/(.*) {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host some-cool-api.test.io;
  proxy_pass https://10.0.0.2/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

I tried the above but it's not matching the route

here is an example of what the URL will look like:

```
"/api/v1/schools/51/courses/231/years/3595/api_end_point?thing_1=0&thing2=0&thing_3=0&thing_4=0&thing_5=0&thing_6=0&thig_7=11250&thing_8=0"
```

Any idea's on how to do the above?

Comment: You need to use a `~` if this is a regular expression location. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Thank you very much @RichardSmith that seems to be working. I will tail the log on the other side to see if the query string is coming out well